# How to get the name of a grandchild collection property with Html.NameFor?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

Suppose I have the following classes:

```
class FooViewModel
{
     // ...Other scalar properties
     public IEnumerable<BarViewModel> Bars { get; set; }
}

class BarViewModel
{
     // ...Other scalar properties
     public IEnumerable<BazViewModel> Bazs { get; set; }
}

class BazViewModel
{
     // ...Other scalar properties
}
```

and I have a view with an instance of `FooViewModel` as the model. I used `@Html.NameFor(m => m.Bars)` to get the value `Bars` from my view. Now I tried to get the value `Bazs` from my view and I have tried the following:

```
<script>
     // bazs returns empty string
     var bazs = '@Html.NameFor(m => m.Bars.Select(bar => bar.Bazs))';

      // bazs returns empty string as well
     var bazs = '@Html.NameFor(m => m.Bars.SelectMany(bar => bar.Bazs))';
</script>
```

How can a get the string value `Bazs` (from `FooViewModel`) and render it in a javascript variable?

Comment: Possibly because `bar.Bazs` is returning one or more objects and not a property? You can put a breakpoint in the Razor code to see what's being returned. Incidentally, it is considered better to have the linq in your controller and pass the results to the View.

Comment: @markpsmith In my class structure described above, `bar.Bazs` **is** a property. I didn't put this `string` value in my view model as I don't want to pollute my view model with information not used in model binding.